# How to set default ScrollTop and ScrollLeft to a popup window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have the code below where I want to open a link with `window.open()` and I want to set default `ScrollTop()` and `ScrollLeft()` to the popup window.
thx.

```
function DoLink(){
window.open('http://translate.google.com/#', '_blank'," width=400, height=400")
}

<input type="button" value="OpenLink" onclick="DoLink()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find if there is an ID on the page you want to open and set the url in the form of:

```
http://xxxxxxx.xxx/#idOfElement
```

Comment: the page that I want to open is :`http://translate.google.com/#`. how do I find its ID?

Comment: This page is already very short. I don't understand why you want to scroll to somewhere...

Comment: the idea is to scroll to the `Translate TO` side of the popup window. now it shows the `Translate FROM`.